# DataGridView flickers even when masked by transparent window

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, flicker

I have an issue with a DataGridView control.  During certain operations, the grid is covered by a semi-transparent dialog (to indicate to users of the operation and prevent users from pressing buttons, etc.).  The grid updates at about 1Hz during this time.  Under Windows XP, the DataGridView control occasionally "flickers" above the masking dialog for a second - not enough time to actually do anything, but a bit of an eyesore nonetheless.  I've also noticed that on my development machine, which runs Window 7, the problem doesn't show up.  I'm using .NET v3.5. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the dialog modal? Do you have a test snippet?

Comment: Assuming you used Opacity for the Dialog, this has to be a video adapter artifact.  It is the one that implements the transparency, it's done with hardware overlays.  Intel graphics perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange flicker problem with Xp only (although that's where the similarities end). Give this a try in the form that's giving you the problem:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
Get
    Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
    cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
    Return cp
End Get
End Property
```

Comment: What style bit is that? DoubleBuffer?

Comment: I looked this up about 6 months back and just have it in my code that fixed a similar problem. I believe is this what the bit is: WS_EX_TRANSPARENT   Specifies that a window created with this style is to be transparent. That is, any windows that are beneath the window are not obscured by the window. A window created with this style receives WM_PAINT messages only after all sibling windows beneath it have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Win32 Form opacity isn't real opacity - but a copy of the images beneath it.  This is the cause of the flicker and not something I have ever seen a way to work around.

Your Win7 issue is also having it - but since that machine and graphic card process much faster, you aren't actually seeing the redraw.

WPF uses true opacity and as such will not have this problem.